# How can I use access method for file extension?

Tags: c, file

I use access in order to understand file is exist or not.

```
char file[100];
strcpy(file, "/home/asd/test.txt");
if(access(file, F_OK) >= 0)
{
    printf("file is exist \n");
}
else
{
    printf("file is not exist \n");
}
```

I try to understand is there any file with txt extension or not so I want to use this code for file extension not file name. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not a C person but glob kinda sounds like something you're looking for: http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob :)

Comment: File extensions are meaningless of POSIX.

Comment: Hah! Wrote the first C since university and posted a minimal working example as an answer. Hope that helps you @user4757345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've thrown together a minimal solution using `glob` which could serve you as a base for proper code. It lacks proper error handling but that's something you can work out from examples like [this one](https://github.com/perusio/linux-programming-by-example/blob/master/book/ch12/ch12-glob.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glob.h>

int main() {
    glob_t results;
    int r = glob("/tmp/*.txt", 0, 0, &results);
    if (r == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "text files found");
    } else if (r == GLOB_NOMATCH) {
        fprintf(stdout, "No files found");
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "glob error");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution looks nice